# What is the total thread count(executed over time, not parallel) for CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing

I need to execute a function about 10^11 times. The function is self-contained and requires one integer as input, let's call it f(n). The range of n is in fact 0 < n < 10^11. We can ignore inclusion of endpoints, I just need the concept about running something of this magnitude in terms of indexes on CUDA.

I want to run this function using CUDA, but I have troubles conceptually. Namely, I know how to simulate my n, mentioned above, using the blocks and threads indexes. As shown in slide 40 of, [nVidia Tutorial](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-cuda-c-basics.pdf)  But, what happens when n>TotalNumberOfThreadsPer_CUDA_Call.

Essentially, does the thread count and block count reset for every call I make to run functions on CUDA? If so, is there a simple way to simulate n, as described earlier, for arbitrarily large n?

Thanks.

Comment: Make several kernel calls and pass an offset as argument? `myKernel(size_t startOffset) { size_t idx = startOffset + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; ... }` Or make a loop in your kernel. `for (size_t idx = blockDim.x * ...; idx < 10^11; idx += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) { ... }`

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae you should realy write more answers to wipe questions off the unanswered tab. +1 for your comment

Comment: @MichaelHaidl Sorry, it's a bad habit I have indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common pattern when you want to process more elements than there are threads is to simply loop over your data in grid-sized chunks:

```
__global__ void kernel(int* data, size_t size) {
    for (size_t idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
         idx < size;
         idx += gridDim.x * blockDim.x) {
        // do something with data[idx] ...
    }
}
```

Another option is to launch several consecutive kernels with a start offset:

```
__global__ void kernel(int* data, size_t size, size_t offset) {
    size_t idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + offset;

    if (idx < size) {
        // do something with data[idx] ...
    }
}

// Host code
dim3 gridSize = ...;
dim3 blockSize = ...;
for (size_t offset = 0; offset < totalWorkSize; offset += gridSize * blockSize) {
    kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(data, totalWorkSize, offset);
}
```

In both cases, you can process an "arbitrarily large" number of elements. You're still limited by `size_t`, so for 10^11 elements you will need to compile your code for 64 bits.

Comment: These two options will do it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store the data instead of just computing it, you will need to do it in an iterative method. 10^11 values of any type are not going to fit in GPU memory.

I haven't compiled this code, but hopefully you'll get the gist.

```
__device__ double my_function(int value);

__global__ void my_kernel(int* data, size_t offset, size_t chunk_size) {

    size_t idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t stride = gridDim.x*blockDim.x;

    while(idx<chunk_size){
    data[idx]=my_function(idx+offset);
    idx+=stride;    
    }
}

void runKernel(size_t num_values){

    size_t block_size = 128;
    size_t grid_size  = 1024;
    size_t free_mem, total_mem;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total);

    size_t chunk_size = sizeof(double)/free_mem;
    double *data;
    cudaMalloc(&data, chunk_size);

    for(size_t i=0; i<num_values; i+=chunk_size){
        my_kernel<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(data, i, chunk_size);
        //copy to host and process
        //or call another kernel on device to process further
    }
    //process remainder of values that need to be run assuming num_values%chunk_size!=0
}
```

Comment: For each CUDA call, results are stored in memory, sent to RAM and then written to file. So I store, move, copy, clear and repeat. Thanks for your suggestion.